# Breaking a table up if too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table inside of a div with a set height. The rows are horizontal:

```
<div height="600px">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that the content in the table is dynamic so sometimes the table will outgrow the div and keep on extending downwards. Is there a way to make the rows grow horizontally instead of vertically once it reaches the edge of the div?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could try `style="overflow-y:scroll"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following jQuery function:

```
$("table").each(function() {
    var tableRows = $(this).find('tr');
    if(tableRows.length > 12) {
        var firstRows = [];
        tableRows.each(function(index) {
            if(index < 12)
                firstRows.push($(this));
            else {
                var content = $(this).html();
                firstRows[index%12].append(content);
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this property to your div:

```
overflow:auto;
```

You can also specify horizontal or vertical scroll, like this:

```
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:auto;
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

This works in jsfiddle (couldn't figure out how to save) http://jsfiddle.net/

you had invalid html by the way (`<th><td>`)

```
<div style="height:30px; background-color:red; overflow-y:scroll">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it to scroll. The content in the cell is very short so I would just look 10x better if it could grow horizontally